# How to prevent form to submit in user availability check process?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a registration form where i am checking user availability using jquery, but when user is not available form should not be submitted. How to prevent it to submitted in not availability case. My code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#email').change(function() {
        status=0;
        user=$('#email').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"verify-user.php",
            data:{'user':user},
            success:function(data){
                if(data=='1'){
                    $("#show_msg").html('<span style="color:#F00;">Not avilable</span>');
                }else if(data=='0'){  
                    $("#show_msg").html('<span style="color:#093;">Avilable</span>');
                }
            }
        });  
    });
});
```

Please help me. Your help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to prevent form submission is tied to the event - in this case:

`$('#email').change`

You need to pass the event to your event handler function as an argument, and add

```
event.preventDefault()
```

to your email change handler. However, since you are calling your validation via Ajax, I believe you'll have to manually submit the form if your validation succeeds. Edited code below - not tested, but hopefully will lead you in the right direction.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#email').change(function(event) {

        status=0;

        user=$('#email').val();

        // prevent default action
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

            type:"post",

            url:"verify-user.php",

            data:{'user':user},

            success:function(data){

                if(data=='1'){

                    $("#show_msg").html('<span style="color:#F00;">Not avilable</span>');

                } else if (data=='0') {  

                    $("#show_msg").html('<span style="color:#093;">Avilable</span>');

                   //submit your form if validation succeeds
                    $("#your-form-id").submit();

            }

        }

    });  

});

});
```

Comment: Thank You for reply. Your code is good but when i use this code for true condition form submitted without checking any other validation means if i left other fields blank that field are not validating and form is submitted

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use an `if` statement?

```
var user=$('#email').val();
if (!user) {
   return;
}

$.ajax({
```